# Ruby - Capybara verifying parent class

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have a scenario where if id is "< Prev" then the parent class must be "disabled" and if id is not ="< Prev" then the parent class should not have "disabled"

```
<li class="disabled">
  <a href="#" id="< Prev">
    Prev
  </a>
</li>
```

Can any help me writing the code using Ruby, Capybara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've already found the 'a' element and have it in a variable named `link`

```
if link[:id] == "< Prev"
  expect(link).to match_selector("li.disabled > a")
else
  expect(link).to match_selector("li:not(.disabled) > a")
end
```

should verify what you specified

Answer (score 1):

You could check that the page doesn't have the element that would fail the expected state:

```
page.should have_no_css("li:not(.disabled) > a[id='< Prev']")
```